# Zoom with a drawing view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, zooming, drawrect

I'm looking for a solution in order to have a beautiful zoom on a drawing view.
In my app, I have a view with an other UIView (which is used like a drawing view) and when I draw a stroke on it, the stroke is perfect. But when I zoom the view, I have this really ugly effect (a pixelised stroke) : [image: screen shot]
<sub>(source: [imagup.com](http://data.imagup.com/10/1160827911.5509png))</sub>

[url image](https://www.imagup.com/)

Is there a solution in order to have a proper stroke ?

My UIViewController has a hierarchy like that :

- UIViewController

  - ScrollView

    - View zoomable (defined with the viewForZoomingInScrollView method)

      - Image view
      - Drawing view

Thanks a lot !

Regards,
Sébastien ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the process of making a vector drawing application and let me tell you, this is NOT a trivial task to do correctly and requires quite a bit of work.

Some issues to keep in mind:

- If you are not using vector graphics (CGPaths, for example, are
  vectors) you will NOT be able to remove the pixelation.  A UIImage,
  for example, only has so much resolution.
- In order to get your drawing to not look pixelated, you are going to
  have to redraw everything.  If you have a lot of drawing, this can be
  an expensive task to perform.
- Having good resolution WHILE zooming is nearly impossible because it would require an excessively large context and your drawing would likely exceed the capabilities of the device

I use core graphics to do my drawing, so the way I solved this issue was by allocating and managing multiple CGContexts and using them as buffers.  I have one context that is ALWAYS kept at my least zoomed level (scale factor of 1).  That context is drawn into at all times and makes it so that when unzooming completely, no time is spent redrawing since it is already done.  Another context is used soley for drawing when zoomed.  When not zoomed, that context is ignored (since it will have to be redrawn based on the new zoom level anyway).  A high level algorithm for how I perform my zooming is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
         //draw an image from the unzoomedContext into my current view

             //set the scale transformation of my current view to be equal to "currentZoom", a property of the view that keeps track of the actual zoom level
    }
    else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
         //determine the new zoom level and transform the current view, keeping track in the currentZoom property

             //zooming will be pixelated.
    }
    else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
             if(currentZoom == 1.0)
             {
                   //you are done because the unzoomedContext image is already drawn into the view!
             }
             else
             {
                   //you are zoomed in and will have to do special drawing

                   //perform drawing into your zoomedContext
                   //scale the zoomedContext

                   //set the scale of your current view to be equal to 1.0

                   //draw the zoomedContext into the current view.  It will not be pixelated!

                   //any drawing done while zoomed needs to be "scaled" based on your current zoom and translation amounts and drawn into both contexts
             }

    }

}
```

This gets even more complicated for me because I have additional buffers for the buffers because drawing images of my paths is much faster than drawing paths when there is lots of drawing.

Between managing multiple contexts, tweaking your code to draw efficiently into multiple contexts, following proper OOD, scaling new drawing based on your current zoom and translation, etc, this is a mountain of a task.  Hopefully this either motivates you and puts you on the right track, or you decide that getting rid of that pixelation isn't worth the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution: tell the view to use a `CATiledLayer` as backing layer, then tell the view how many levels of zoom it supports. This worked for me, my drawing methods get automatically called when the (parent) view is zoomed.

A short explanation of `levelsOfDetail` and `levelsOfDetailBias`:

- `levelsOfDetail` determine how many zooming levels there are in total
- `levelsOfDetailBias` determine how many of those are zooming in.

So in my example I have 4 zooming levels, 3 are zoomed in and 1 is the non-zoomed level, meaning my view only redraws when zooming in.

```
@imprementation MyZoomableView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        ((CATiledLayer *)self.layer).levelsOfDetail = 4;
        ((CATiledLayer *)self.layer).levelsOfDetailBias = 3;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I tried this but my app crashes due to memory issue, randomly throwing SIGABRT at multiple places. I have written a sample to show how I am using this, in actual app the drawing is really bigger and has texts and icons too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191771/draw-zoomable-vector-in-ios-using-coregraphics

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self setContentScaleFactor:scale];` in your `scrollViewDidEndZooming:` delegate method.